# How to open a new chrome window with Puppeteer instead of tab?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am connecting to an headless chrome docker image with puppeteer.connect(). However using puppeteer.launch() within a container/os works because chrome and your node app are on the same network and you can spawn multiple windows each with its own tab. How do you achieve this with puppeteer.connect()?

Working Puppeteer connection code to a standalone headless chrome:

```
const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.100.100:9222/json/version`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        const { webSocketDebuggerUrl } = await await response.json()
        const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
            browserWSEndpoint: webSocketDebuggerUrl
        })
```

Docker image launch:

```
docker run -d -p 9223:9222 --name chromedp chromedp/headless-shell --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu --headless
```

I am aware that spawning multiple windows may be resource intensive but my use case requires it. Thanks.